# Cannot install Oracle Forms on Windows 7

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms, failed-installation

I have downloaded Oracle Forms but I am not able to install it in Windows 7 (32bit). I am getting an error

```
Using paramFile: ..\install\oraparam.ini


Checking installer requirements...

Checking operating system version: must be 5.0, 5.1 or 5.2.    Actual 6.1
                                      Failed <<<<

Exiting Oracle Universal Installer, log for this session can be found at C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\installActions2012-06-09_09-56-47PM.log

Please press Enter to exit...
```

Kindly assist me in installation.

Comment: What is the full version of Oracle Forms you are trying to install?

Comment: Oracle Developer Suite 10g (10.1.2.0.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a tickbox next to it to ignore the condition. Put a tick to it & the setup will continue.

Comment: I am getting this error in command prompt when OUI starts.There isn't any tickbox .

Comment: I got a link where it showed me the procedure on how to install the software.https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=587743 .There is a section in the forum "Installing Forms 10g" where it has given me the correct procedure.I followed that procedure .But I am only able to go through the point no 7.After point no 7 the OUI disappears and nothing is happening .Can anybody explain me what to do?

Comment: For me, after step 7 (smtp server) I had 3 fields :
 - for the first field, clic browse and select product.xml from ds_windows_x86_101202_disk1\stage
 - for the last two fields, you can change Oracle Home Name and Oracle Home Path.

and the installation will continue until it asks you for the "second" products.xml file.

Answer (score 8):

if you're using windows 7 then right click on the setup file and properties and do like this

```
Change Compatibility Mode 

Click Check On Run This Program In Compatibility Mode For:
Windows Xp Service Pack 3 

then setup will run and oracle will install on windows 7
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Under Oracle Reports 10g directory go to install folder then open `oraparam` file in note pad and change `[Certified Versions]` windows values like bellow:

```
[Certified Versions]
Windows=5.0,5.1,5.2,6.1
```